# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\lvert f-g\rvert^2\, dx\leq 0\implies f=g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to argue that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\lvert f-g\rvert^2\, dx\leq 0\implies f=g$?

I think, it is very easy.

We have $\lvert f-g\rvert^2\geq 0$, hence my monotonicity of the integral, we also have
$$
0\leq\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\lvert f-g\rvert^2\, dx.
$$

Hence by assumption, the integral is 0.

Since the integrand is non-negative, the only chance to get the integral to 0 is when the integrand is 0 on whole $\mathbb{R}^d$, meaning f=g.

Is this an valid argumentation?

Comment: I think your argumentation is all right

Comment: Yup you're argument is correct  (and $f = g$ almost everywhere).